# Why is my code giving wrong output, translating inches into centimetres and vice versa

Tags: python, math, translation

My code is giving incorrect output while everything seems to be alright.

The purpose of the code is to translate inches into centimetres and vice versa.

For example, with inpput `cm` then `6`, the output is:

```
inch: 6, centimeter: 15.24

But it should be:
```

inch: 2.362, centimeter: 6

````
 
Code:
```py
def intocm():
    ms = input('What is it? (inch-in or centimeter-cm): ')
    am = int(input('How many of it: '))
    intocm = 2.54
    global inch
    global cm

    if ms == 'inch' or 'in':
        cm = am * intocm
        inch = am

    elif ms == 'centimeter' or ms == 'cm':
        cm = am
        inch = cm / intocm

    print(f'inch: {inch}, centimeter: {cm}')


intocm()
````

Comment: Compare your if statement to your elif statement.

Comment: everything is alright with if and elif

Comment: `if ms=="inch" or "in"` is wrong. It should be `if ms=="inch" or ms=="in"`. Otherwise it'll be treated as `if ((ms=="inch") or ("in"))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Actually, @DrEsperanto, it DOES answer your question exactly.  Apply what that says to your first if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an equality test in your `if` statement, and you should be using `float` (not `int`). Like,

```
def intocm():
    ms=input("What is it? (inch-in or centimeter-cm): ")
    am=float(input("How many of it: "))
    intocm=2.54
    global inch
    global cm
    if ms=="inch" or ms=="in":
        cm=am*intocm
        inch=am
    elif ms=="centimeter" or ms=="cm":
        cm=am
        inch=cm/intocm
    print(f'inch: {inch}, centimeter: {cm}')
```

Which I ran

```
What is it? (inch-in or centimeter-cm): cm
How many of it: 2.54
inch: 1.0, centimeter: 2.54
```

(twice)

```
What is it? (inch-in or centimeter-cm): in
How many of it: 1
inch: 1.0, centimeter: 2.54
```

Which seems correct.

Comment: For this type of comparison, I would prefer the approach used by @eshirvana, using the `in` operator than a double comparison.

Comment: @RufusVS I'd prefer a straight `else` instead of an `elif` (but also maybe using  `if ms.lower() in ["inch" , "in"]:`)

Answer (score 1):

the issue is with logic in your if `if ms=="inch" or "in":`

you can write it better with `in`:

```
def intocm():
    ms=input("What is it? (inch-in or centimeter-cm): ")
    am=int(input("How many of it: "))
    intocm=2.54
    if ms in ["inch" , "in"]:
        cm=am*intocm
        inch=am
    elif ms in ["centimeter" , "cm"]:
        cm=am
        inch=cm/intocm
    print(f'inch: {inch}, centimeter: {cm}')
intocm()
```

Answer (score 0):

if ms=="inch" or "in" is wrong. It should be if ms=="inch" or ms=="in". Otherwise it'll be treated as if ((ms=="inch") or ("in"))

Answer (score 0):

The code is failing because of the first if condition. It should be similar to your elif condition.

In your code it is
if ms=="inch" or "in":

but it should be
if ms=="inch" or ms=="in":